# ViewModel construction crashing application

Tags: c#, xamarin, viewmodel

I'm trying to learn Xamarin Forms by making a Contact with Notes (One to Many).
I've done a ListView with a ContactsViewModel binding working well.

So now I'm trying to make an edit context button :

```
public void OnEdit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Contact contact = ((MenuItem)sender).CommandParameter as Contact;
    Navigation.PushAsync(new ContactPage(contact));
}
```

So here I send my contact to the page with basic entry, the constructor of this ContactPage :

```
public ContactPage(Contact contact)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = new ContactViewModel()
    {
        Id = contact.Id,
        Firstname = contact.Firstname,
        Lastname = contact.Lastname,
        Email = contact.Email,
        Address = contact.Address,
        Notes = contact.Notes
    };
}
```

But when I click on my edit context button I get a crash of the application I don't understand why.

Here is the repository if you need to look deeper into the code :
https://github.com/yerffeog/Contactium

Thanks for your attention I'm also open to any code criticisms as well as improvements.

When removing arguments it works but when I put just one argument I get a crash.

Comment: Can you change `Contact Contact` to `Contact contact`? Probably unrelated to your issue but its bugging me

Comment: What is the error you get when it crashes?

Comment: Can it be `contact` var doesn't initialized from `CommandParameter`?

Comment: any time you have a crash like this, the first thing you should do is wrap the suspect code in a try/catch block to determine what the root exception is

Comment: I checked with breakpoints but I receive the right informations.

Comment: I put it in a try catch with a Debug WriteLine but I don't get any message on the exception just a crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to make sure a valid value is being passed to the page.

```
public async void OnEdit(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    Contact contact = ((MenuItem)sender).CommandParameter as Contact;
    if(contact != null) {
        var contactPage = new ContactPage(contact);
        await Navigation.PushAsync(contactPage);
    }
}
```

Based on the repository code provided,

This view model

```
public class ContactViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ContactViewModel()
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Event when property changed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="s">string</param>
    void OnPropertyChanged(string s)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(s));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Id of the contact.
    /// </summary>
    public int Id {
        get
        {
            return Id;
        }

        set
        {
            Id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Id));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Lastname of the contact.
    /// </summary>
    public string Lastname {
        get
        {
            return Lastname;
        }

        set
        {
            Lastname = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Lastname));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Firstname of the contact.
    /// </summary>
    public string Firstname {
        get
        {
            return Firstname;
        }

        set
        {
            Firstname = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Firstname));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Email of the contact.
    /// </summary>
    public string Email {
        get
        {
            return Email;
        }

        set
        {
            Email = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Email));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Address of the contact.
    /// </summary>
    public string Address
    {
        get
        {
            return Address;
        }

        set
        {
            Address = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Address));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Notes of the contact.
    /// </summary>
    public List<Note> Notes
    {
        get
        {
            return Notes;
        }

        set
        {
            Notes = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Notes));
        }
    }
}
```

The above will fail as the properties refer back to themselves which would cause a stack overflow and crash the application.

To avoid repeated code create a base view model with the basics

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    /// <summary>
    /// Event when property changed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="s">string</param>
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string member = "") {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(member));
    }
}
```

From there make sure the view model has backing fields for the exposed properties.

```
public class ContactViewModel : ViewModelBase {
    private string id;
    /// <summary>
    /// Id of the contact.
    /// </summary>
    public int Id {
        get { return id; }
        set {
            id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    string lastname;
    /// <summary>
    /// Lastname of the contact.
    /// </summary>
    public string Lastname {
        get { return lastname; }
        set {
            lastname = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    string firstname
    /// <summary>
    /// Firstname of the contact.
    /// </summary>
    public string Firstname {
        get { return firstname; }
        set {
            firstname = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    string email;
    /// <summary>
    /// Email of the contact.
    /// </summary>
    public string Email {
        get { return email; }
        set {
            email = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    string address;
    /// <summary>
    /// Address of the contact.
    /// </summary>
    public string Address {
        get { return address; }
        set {
            address = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    string notes;
    /// <summary>
    /// Notes of the contact.
    /// </summary>
    public List<Note> Notes {
        get { return notes; }
        set {
            notes = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I checked with breakpoints but I receive the right informations. Even with this check I still get a crash.

Comment: @GeoffreyMigliacci Ok, when stepping through the code, at which line do you get the crash?

Comment: @nikosi is right, the way you have written your properties will lead to infinite recursion

Comment: Thanks ! Sorry  for wasting your time on such a "basic" error and thanks you for your answer !

Comment: @GeoffreyMigliacci yeah this turned out to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I would suggest you review your other viewmodels to make sure the same mistake is not repeated. I noticed the same in NoteViewModel